# How to return the diagonal line in table with xpath query?

Tags: xml, xpath

given the following xml document:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td>  <td>B</td>  <td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>  <td>2</td>  <td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td>  <td>b</td>  <td>c</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to write xpath query to get the diagonal line of the table.
I thought about the following query:  `//td[count(parent::td/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]`  But it's not working (it returns "No Match!" as result).

In the example above, the query need to return `<td>A</td> <td>2</td> <td>c</td>`

What is the problem with this query ?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify which version of xpath you are using and whether you know the number in advance the number of `<tr>`s in the table.

Comment: @JackFleeting the version is 3.0 , and No, I don't know the number.

Comment: Can you explain me please what is the problem with my query (that mentioned in the question) ?@JackFleeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  Just change

```
//td[count(parent::td/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]
```

to

```
//td[count(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]
```

or

```
//td[count(../preceding-sibling::tr)+1]
```

and your XPath will select

```
<td>A</td><td>2</td><td>c</td>
```

as desired.

### See also

- [XPath parent axis not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73065256/290085)

---

**Update to answer follow-up question:**

> Can you explain me please how to read the `preceding-sibling::tr` in the following expression: `//td[count(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]`?

`preceding-sibling::tr` selects all `tr` sibling elements before the context element.  By counting those for the parent of a given `td` element, the whole XPath is able to select the diagonal `td` elements because the count of the preceding parent `tr` elements effectively gives the row number, and `//td[` *row number* `]` yields only those `td` elements where the column number (the n<sup>th</sup> child `td`) equals the row number.

Comment: Can you explain me please how to read the `preceding-sibling::tr` in the following expression: `//td[count(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr)+1]`?

Comment: Answer updated to answer your follow-up and explain the XPath overall.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you're getting `"No Match!"` no match for the query in your question: the result should be `<td>A</td> <td>1</td> <td>a</td>` since the query resolves to `1` (because of the `+1` at the end); there is no `//td[parent::td]` so the count is 0.

Since you are using xpath 3.0, you can try:

```
for $k in (1 to count(//tr)) return (//tr[$k]/td[$k])
```

It works on the table in the question.