# XPath parent axis not behaving as expected

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML document:

```
<table>
<tr>   <td>A</td>         <td>B</td>         <td>C</td>     </tr>
<tr>   <td>D</td>       <td>E</td>    <td>E</td>      </tr>
<tr>   <td>F</td>    <td>G</td>         <td>H</td>      </tr>
</table>
```

I get different results for the following expressions and I don't understand what is the reason for that.

for: `//td[parent::td]` I get an empty set (namely, "No match").
for: `//td[..]` I get list of all the `td` elements.

I don't understand what is the difference between the expressions, because that `..` is shortcut of `parent::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference:

- `//td[parent::td]` selects nothing because no `td` elements have `td` parents.
- `//td[..]` selects all `td` elements because all `td` elements have a parent.

Both `//td[parent::*]` and `//td[..]` would select all `td` elements.

Comment: But the meaning of `//td[parent::td]` its not the following ? Any `td` that exists for him parent. Namely, `parent::td` not say "the parent of `td`" ?

Comment: No, read `parent::td` as the `td` element on the parent axis of the context element.  The context element in the predicate of `//td[parent::td]` is going to be a `td` element.  There is no `td` element with a `td` element parent in your XML.

Comment: Can you explain me please how to read the following expression `//tr/child::td`?

Comment: Read it the same as `//tr/td`, that is, *all `td` element children of all `tr` elements in the document.*